# Can't add some data in vec into loop

Tags: rust

I'm newbie in Rust. Please, explain to me why I can't add new value in vec in the code:

```
    let mut vec1 = vec![1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
    let mut vec2 = vec![1, 1, 1];
    let mut vec3 = vec![1, 1, 1, 1];

    let queues = vec![vec1, vec2, vec3];

    for &mut i in queues.iter() {
        i.push(1);
    }
```

I think I don't understand borrowing but I can't find good an example for this case.

Comment: You need to mark `queues` as mutable: `let mut queues` and then use `.iter_mut()` instead of `iter()`

Comment: In addition to the above, note that the three vectors don't have to be declared `mut` because they get _moved into_ the `queues` vector, which takes ownership of them.

Answer (score 2):

The thing between `for` and `in` is a pattern, just like what comes after `let`. Patterns are how you create bindings in rust.

So when you do `for &mut i in queues.iter()`, it's like you're doing `let &mut i = &vec1` for the first element, `let &mut i = &vec2` for the second, etc. This doesn't work because `&mut i` is trying to destructure a mutable reference, which `&vec1` is not.

You can write `for &i in queues.iter()`, and the types check out, but this is also not what you want. This version tries to move `i` out of the reference, which can't be done, and even if it could, that item would no longer be part of `queues` so pushing to it would not affect the original value.

So instead, you can bind the whole reference: `for i in queues.iter()`. This is like `let i = &vec1`, which makes `i` of the type `&Vec`. This is a reference to data that is owned by and stays part of `queues`.

And lastly, you are trying to mutate it, so you need to use `iter_mut` instead, which gives out `&mut` (mutable) references instead of `&` (shared) references.

You also need to declare `queues` as mutable.

```rs
let mut queues = vec![vec1, vec2, vec3];

for i in queues.iter_mut() {
    i.push(1);
}
```